# All the times when Movies & TV SE made it big

Tags: discussion

Movies & TV Stack Exchange has had the opportunity to be covered by media companies like The Guardian and Business Insider lots of times. So this post is to list all these moments of glory in the form of answers.

Make sure to check other answers before listing to avoid duplicate entries.

Answer (score 13):

Recently we got the question about the red room from *Stranger Things*:

[What is the purpose of this "red room" in Stranger Things?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102266/1190)

But most of us might not have expected how viral it would go.

It became a popular [meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXKpt.jpg) and got covered on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/comments/cigy8z/we_are_now_this_old/). And many popular tweets on Twitter ([1](https://twitter.com/kezamacdonald/status/1154819809198190592?s=20), [2](https://twitter.com/soapachu/status/1154711824023076866?s=20)).

Also on **The Guardian**: [In the dark: why the Stranger Things ‘red room’ is confusing younger fans](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/shortcuts/2019/jul/29/in-the-dark-why-the-stranger-things-red-room-is-confusing-younger-fans)

And on **Business Insider**: [A hilarious question about a photography darkroom on 'Stranger Things' is going viral: 'What is the purpose of this 'red room'?'](https://www.businessinsider.in/A-hilarious-question-about-a-photography-darkroom-on-Stranger-Things-is-going-viral-What-is-the-purpose-of-this-red-room/articleshow/70403933.cms)

And also I am feeling **OLD** now.

Comment: this => *And also I am feeling OLD now.* ;)

Comment: LOL yeah this became pretty big

Comment: That Guardian article is _horrible_ IMO.  Who came up with that format?  I really can't understand what I'm supposed to be reading.  Is it a conversation between two people?  Who and why?

Comment: Aw, my highest-voted comment ever got moved to chat :(

Comment: @OrangeDog maybe ask the mods for undelete

Comment: @AnkitSharma to be fair, it wasn't useful

Comment: @OrangeDog If it helps, the chatrooms will be auto-deleted in a few days, too, anyway. ;-)

Comment: It has also made its way into [German mainstream newspapers](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/stranger-things-fans-raetseln-ueber-den-magischen-roten-raum-16311735.html), but that is already the secondary iteration which only references the internet hype itself without linking to the M&TV question that incited it all anymore, although they transcribe quotes from the actual question on an "online forum".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson you can add it in answer I guess

Comment: Nah, it's really just the extension of the memeization process, since there is no link back to the site anymore.

Answer (score 6):

So who doesn't like a good conspiracy especially when we are talking about Pixar, so while covering the same **The Guardian** made this article:

[The great big Pixar conspiracy](https://www.theguardian.com/film/filmblog/2013/jul/17/pixar-fan-conspiracy-theory)

And referenced another question from Movies & TV SE:

[Why doesn't Marty use the other DeLorean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/5736/1190)

Answer (score 5):

It's not always rainbows and sunshine but also misinterpretation which was also done by

**The Guardian:** [Politeness costs nothing, but it may stop people understanding you](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/may/22/politeness-costs-nothing-but-it-may-stop-people-understanding-you)

They focused on one of my own questions:

[What is to the west of Westeros?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100921/1190)

and one from the German Language Stackexchnage:

https://german.stackexchange.com/q/52280/22016

But with some possible ignorance and misinterpretation of the intent of the posts. And also got covered on the Main meta:

[How is misrepresentation of Stack Exchange in the media (and in science) handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328531/182734)

Answer (score 5):

### Ars Technica — November 22, 2018

In the article "[50 years ago, *Star Trek*’s history was sealed with the Uhura-Kirk kiss](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/11/50-years-ago-star-treks-history-was-sealed-with-the-uhura-kirk-kiss/)", they cleared up this misconception:

> The smooching scene has been commonly referred to as television’s first interracial kiss—but there’s [compelling evidence](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57324/was-kirk-and-uhuras-kiss-in-star-trek-really-the-first-interracial-kiss-on-tv) that it actually wasn’t.

The hyperlink pointed to [Was Kirk and Uhura's kiss in Star Trek really the first interracial kiss on TV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57324/12783), hosted here on Movies & TV Stack Exchange.